# Store result in new Array if Id from URL is matching with id of Result

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

In my LWC I'm showing all records in page and I want to show only those records which are matching with record id from url.
I tried with @api recordId but that didn't bring result I'm doubtful whether my implementation was correct.
I also tried with event.target.value but that showing error.

```
import getActiveSessions from '@salesforce/apex/DCController.TBT_getActiveSessions';


_getActiveSessions(){
  getActiveSessions().then(response=>{
    this.dataToDisplay = response
    // for(let i=0;i< this.dataToDisplay.length; i++){
    //     if(this.dataToDisplay[i].id == recordId){           // I tried this way but not getting through it
    //         this.clientData[i] = this.dataToDisplay[i];  
    //     }
    // }
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
  ;
  console.log('client data '+clientData);
}
```

event query running in apex class and that result is coming to LWC by getActiveSessions method

```
Select Id, Subject, WhatId, WhoId, Who.Name, EndDate, EndDateTime,Start_Date_Time__c , OwnerId, ActivityDate, ActivityDateTime, Facilities__c,Facilities__r.Name, Services__c, Appointment_Status__c, Description, DC_Session_Start_Time__c, DC_Session_End_Time__c, DC_Session_Run_Time__c, DC_Session_Status__c, DC_Session_Last_Start_Time__c, End_Time__c, IsRecurrence, DOSSession__c, What.Name From Event'
```

can anyone please look into it and guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1  :
You can send record Id as parameter and get only those records, from that you don't want to filter records in JS.

Like this :

```
_getActiveSessions(){
   getActiveSessions({recordId : this.recordId}).then(response=>{
     this.dataToDisplay = response;
     console.log(response)
   }).catch(error=>{
     console.log(error)
   });
}
```

Approach 2 :
If you want to filter records in JS side then you can do that

```
_getActiveSessions(){
  getActiveSessions().then(response=>{
    this.dataToDisplay = response.map(i=>{
      if(i.id == this.recordId){
        return i;
      }
   })
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```